# Visual Studio 2017 Page Launching Error "Unable To Launch the IIS Express Web Server"

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2017, launching-application

I am using VS2017. After launching page `View In Browser`, it's giving me error as below. I have uninstalled `IIS` from my system and restarted but still it showing me same below error on page launching.

[image]

What is this error and how should I solve it?

Comment: when i get that error, i close the visual studio and delete .vs, bin and obj folders. After all of it, im opening visual studio and clean the solution

Comment: @BerkGarip tried this but still showing me same error while launching.

Comment: You can create a new project and see if the new project can be launched normally. If the new project can be launched normally, it is likely to be a problem with your own project/configuration. If the new project cannot be launched,  It is a problem of the VS environment, you can try to repair VS, Update VS, and then delete all ComponentModelCache files in this path: `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_XXXXX\ComponentModelCache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done everything but still no success. Therefore I have formatted my PC and reinstalled everything. Now everything is running properly.